# SQL: Insert into table_b where table_a has no related row?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mariadb, row

Sorry if a question like this already exists, I haven't found any so far.

I have two tables, `products` and `prices`.

In my `products` table I have many products (thousands), but in `prices` I have set prices only for a few products.

The column that connects them is called `code` (in both tables).

I need to make an INSERT query, that inserts one row into `prices` for each `product` that has no row in `prices`.
How can achieve this?

Comment: Is `code` supposed to be unique in the `prices` table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, it's not! Since an article can have more than one price. Therefore the prices table can have many rows for the same article. But I need to have at least one price for article in order to start working.

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps you just need `LEFT JOIN` somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You may use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with an `EXISTS` clause:

```
INSERT INTO prices (code, col1, col2, ...)
SELECT code, col1, col2, ...
FROM products p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM prices p2 WHERE p1.code = p2.code);
```

Answer (score 1):

This `LEFT JOIN` between `products` and `code`:

```
select p.code, p.column2, p.column3, ...
from products p left join prices pp
on pp.code = p.code
where pp.code is null
```

select all the rows from `products` that do not have a corresponding `code` in `prices`.
 So you can use it in this statement:

```
insert into prices (code, column2, column3, ...)
select p.code, p.column2, p.column3, ...
from products p left join prices pp
on pp.code = p.code
where pp.code is null
```